# Error passing strings and char to bool function

Tags: c++, string, function, parsing

I am trying to create a function that looks at a `'-'` sign and checks whether is a minus sign or a negative sign based on if it has a `' '` (space) in front of it. I am doing so by comparing the current char I have (`infix[x]`) and comparing to `infix[x+1]`; I keep getting error but im unsure if its because im not passing correctly or something else?

```
        for(unsigned x = 0; x < infix.length(); ++x)
        {
             // place numbers (standard, decimal, & negative)
             // numbers onto the 'postfix' string
             if((isdigit(infix[x])) || (infix[x] == '.'))
             {
                 postfix += infix[x];
             }
             else if ((infix[x] == '-'))
             {
                     if(checkfornegative(infix[x], infix)== 1))  // error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
            if(checkfornegative(infix[x], infix)== 1))
            {
                        postfix+= " ";
            }
            else if(checkfornegative(infix[x], infix)== 0))  //error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
                if(checkfornegative(infix[x], infix)== 1))

                {
                    postfix += infix[x];
                }

            }

// This is the function in using
bool checkfornegative(char C, string& QQ)
{
         bool status;
         if((C == '-') && (QQ[C+1] == ' '))
         {
                 status = true;
         }
         else if((C == '-') && (QQ[C+1] != ' '))
         {
                 status =  false;
    }
    return status;
}
```

Comment: Having some context here in terms of a minimal, complete example would help considerably. How are these functions called? What data are you providing?

Comment: Your parentheses aren't balanced, this can't be the code you're running.

Comment: `QQ[C+1]` makes no sense. `C` is a character, not an index in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting compilation errors because you have extra closing parenthesis in the `if` conditions.

```
if(checkfornegative(infix[x], infix)== 1))  // error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
```

Remove the last closing parenthesis from the condition. Same goes for the second condition also.

However, there are several issues in your code but they are not compilation errors.

Comment: That solved it, couldn't see it for the life of me. thanks a lot.